# Uninstall QGIS 2.18 from mac and reinstall. Remembers settings

Tags: qgis-2

Relates to Mac OS 10.14.

I have problems with QGIS 2.18. Plugins not working etc.
(latest problem is not being able to make a virtual raster catalogue of landsat 8 tiles. Error message : 
"The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.")

So I uninstalled QGIS by dragging **QGIS.app** from applications folder to trash and emptying trash.

Reinstalled QGIS 2.18.

Opened QGIS 2.18.

It remembered all the settings etc !

How can I delete QGIS 2.18 to start completely fresh ?
I imagine it's okay to keep the **QGIS-OSX-2.18.28-1.dmg** (this has all the packages required for QGIS to run)
I also have QGIS3 installed on the machine (also problems there) but I take it the two don't interfere, so I don't need to delete QGIS 3?

All help welcome.

Comment: Does your answer refer to Mac or Windows ?

Comment: Can not find org.qgis.qgis.plist  under preferences.   Also can not find .qgis2 under "$HOME" ( I take it that's the same as the name of my harddrive (Macintosh HD) )

Comment: Any idea how to remove QGIS 2.18 and all related frameworks (including GDAL etc) completely, so I can re-install fresh from the QGIS-OSX-2.18.28-1.dmg? I believe it contains all the packages that need to be installed in order for QGIS to run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92631/discussion-between-charlie-mike-and-user2856).